# Diferentes identificadores de sesión antes y después de autentificarse

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla de pedidos donde me guardo la sesión id por si el usuario todavía no se ha registrado o logueado poder ir guardando productos en su 'cesta' de la compra.

Cuando se registra o loguea lo que quiero es obtener el pedido que tiene pendiente esa sesión y asociarlo al usuario que se ha acaba de autentificar.

El problema que tengo es que cuando se da de alta el pedido y se guarda en la tabla de pedidos en el campo sesion el id de sesión no se corresponde con la misma sesión cuando el usuario se ha autentificado. Sin cerrar el navegador y sin salir de la web el identificador de sesión cambia antes y después de autenficarse.

Para obtener el identificador de la sesión lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
$session_id = Session::getId();
```

¿Alguien sabe el motivo que cambie el identificador de sesión?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado el motivo que realice esto. Laravel automáticamente regenera el identificador de sesión para evitar ataques de tipo session fixation.